# Starting Spring Boot application (Vaadin) stuck at running 'npm install'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, npm-install, vaadin14

My Vaadin application used to work fine, but now when I want to start it the application is stuck at running npm install:

> 2022-10-02 15:24:49.482  INFO 27004 --- [           main] dev-updater                              : Running `npm install` to resolve and optionally download frontend dependencies. This may take a moment, please stand by...

And I cant find a way to fix that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `npm install` the first thing you can try is... wait. Sometimes it can be frustratingly slow. I have seen 10 minutes in extreme cases. It is especially slow if you have deleted `package-lock.json` or upgraded a lot of dependencies (like when you upgrade the Vaadin version).

Sometimes you can fix that by manually running `npm install --prefer-offline` once which will make npm spend less time looking for things to update and instead focus on installing the needed packages.

Overall if you run `npm install` manually once, you will better see progress and what is going on. You can even add the `--verbose` flag but that will probably give you more information than what you want.